# Update handle in a product

Tags: layout, upgrade

I am trying to call an update layout handle in a product design custom layout update by inserting this code

```
<update handle="my_handle"/>
```

but nothing appears, if I put the content of that handle it shows up correctly or if I put this code in my xml

```
<default>
    <update handle="my_handle"/>
</default>
```

it works fine so my handle should work.
Is there something that loads those handles before calling the product custom design update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately these are merged in a separate cycle and do not have access to any file-based layout update handles. Sucks!

The alternative strategy is to use the `PRODUCT_[id]` handles in your layout XML. I personally do not like using arbitrary entity IDs in multiple media (i.e. using arbitrary DB-generated values in the filesystem) but this will do the trick.

Comment: As there are not a lot of products that uses this I will do it like that! I didn't know you could do it like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: The strange thing is that delete works, it should be the same... But anyway I hope they will change that soon.